# RPC_ERROR Odoo Server Error When sending Quotation by Email in Persian

Tags: odoo-17

installation environment as followed:

Python 3.10
Odoo17.0
Ubuntu22.04

Detail as followed:

```
RPC_ERROROdoo Server ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1765, in _serve_dbreturn service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retryingresult = func()File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1792, in _serve_ir_httpresponse = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1996, in dispatchresult = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatchresponse = super()._dispatch(endpoint)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 222, in _dispatchresult = endpoint(**request.params)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 722, in route_wrapperresult = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 24, in call_kwreturn self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 20, in _call_kwreturn call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 468, in call_kwresult = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multiresult = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 1077, in onchangesnapshot1 = RecordSnapshot(record, fields_spec)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 1164, in initself.fetch(name)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 1173, in fetchlines = self.record[field_name]File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6590, in getitemreturn self._fields[key].get(self, self.env.registry[self._name])File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2893, in getreturn super().get(records, owner)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1152, in getself.recompute(record)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1367, in recomputeapply_except_missing(self.compute_value, recs)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1340, in apply_except_missingfunc(records)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1389, in compute_valuerecords._compute_field_value(self)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4867, in _compute_field_valuefields.determine(field.compute, self)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 102, in determinereturn needle(*args)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 256, in _compute_attachment_idsrendered_values = composer._generate_template_for_composer(File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 1242, in _generate_template_for_composertemplate_values = self.template_id._generate_template(File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 548, in _generate_templatetemplate._generate_template_attachments(File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 287, in _generate_template_attachmentsreport_name = safe_eval(File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 363, in safe_evalc = test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode, filename=filename)File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 216, in test_exprcode_obj = compile(expr, filename or "", mode)File "<string>", line 1(object.state in ('draft', 'sent') و 'پیش‌فاکتور  - %s' % (object.name)) یا 'سفارش - %s' % (object.name)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

The above server error caused the following client error:
OwlError: An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
at handleError (https://xxxxxx.xxx/web/assets/2c89626/web.assets_web.min.js:916:101)
at App.handleError (https://xxxxxx.xxx/web/assets/2c89626/web.assets_web.min.js:1542:29)
at ComponentNode.initiateRender (https://xxxxxx.xxx/web/assets/2c89626/web.assets_web.min.js:1006:19)

Caused by: RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server ErrorK
at makeErrorFromResponse (https://xxxxxx.xxx/web/assets/2c89626/web.assets_web.min.js:2874:163)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://xxxxxx.xxx/web/assets/2c89626/web.assets_web.min.js:2878:13)K

when clicked on "Send by Email" button in Quotation form page, it caused the above error. In English it works.